# Flutter Dart and Chewie

Tags: dart

My simple question is how do I get the 'position' value and how do I have a function when it changes?

https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

```
_chewieController.videoPlayerController.position;
```

Knowing that position is a **Future(Duration)**.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Duration time;
_chewieController.videoPlayerController.position.then(
    (result){
      time = result;
    }
  );
```

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? If so, I'd greatly appreciate if you'd select the answer and give my answer an upvote. if not, please let me know how I can improve it.